# Cannnot initialize CoinbaseSDK in Nuxt3 project

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, coinbase-api, nuxtjs3

Please, I would like to use [@coinbase/wallet-sdk](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-wallet-sdk) in a Nuxt3 project.

I have tried on a Nuxt2 project and everything works well but not on v3.
Following the [Nuxt3 doc](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/concepts/esm/) I've added the package to *build.transpile* and that error is thrown:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/_nuxt/node_modules/@coinbase/wallet-sdk/dist/index.js?v=e05281e2' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Is Vite the cause of this problem ?

Comment: Looks more like `wallet-sdk` is not written as an ESM module and hence, will not be compatible with Vue3/Nuxt3. At least, `does not provide an export named 'default'` suggests it (the usual error).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [@coinbase/wallet-sdk](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-wallet-sdk) is not written as ESM module and Nuxt3 is, so you will need to use `nodePolyfills from rollup-plugin-polyfill-node` if you are using Nuxt3 With Vite(which is default) then this configuration might help

```
// nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node';

const MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV;

// ↓ Have to check the mode here because this cant run on build
const vitePlugin =
  MODE === 'development'
    ? [
        nodePolyfills({
          include: [
            'node_modules/**/*.js',
            new RegExp('node_modules/.vite/.*js'),
          ],
        }),
      ]
    : [];


// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  buildModules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['@ethersproject', 'ethers'],
  },
  vite: {
    plugins: [...vitePlugin],
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        plugins: [
          // ↓ Needed for build
          nodePolyfills(),
        ],
      },
      // ↓ Needed for build
      commonjsOptions: {
        transformMixedEsModules: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```